# In Eclipse, how do I remove the Debug keyboard shortcut for showing the perspective?

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

For some reason, the Debug perspective's keyboard shortcut is bound to the same shortcut as "Open Resource" for me (<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>). I only want it for Open Resource. I can't seem to find it when I search for 'debug' in the keyboard shortcut part of the preferences.

Comment: Interesting... An alternative could be searching for `Perspectives` (since this is in the `Perspectives` category) and ordering the commands by name, and see if `Debug` is listed, but it may not show up if it's not showing up when you search for it by name.

Comment: @DougSmith: If you can't find it then perhaps try restoring the keys to defaults and giving it a go. And which eclipse version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The command in the keys preferences is called "Show perspective (Debug)". If that is not visible in your version, I would also suggest looking at the filters in the key preferences.

Answer (score -1):

Under File -> Preferences, in the popup under General -> Keys is where the bindings are stored.

Comment: Does it open the debug perspective?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what it does.

Comment: The one you are looking for may be getting filtered from the list.  In the keys window at the bottom left(at least on my version) there is a filters button.  Click on it and uncheck everything.  You can also sort on key binding and then look for the key combination there.  The combination ordering may not be in the order you list, so make sure to check for all variation of the ordering too.